# How to extend an install4j installation with a new Media file

Tags: install4j

We have had to add a new install medium to an install4j installation.

I can see two ways of updating the files on the distribution server.

Firstly, we could copy all the newly generated installation media and the new update.xml file. Here I have the question: in determining whether an update is necessary, is only the field "newVersion" used, or is the check sum also part of the logic?

Secondly, we could copy only the new medium and edit the update.xml with the new entry. This would be my prefered method as the newly generated versions of old install media would not have to be tested. The question is whether a hand edited update.xml is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new entry to updates.xml manually. From the new compilation output, locate the entry for the new media file and insert it into the old updates.xml.